# Resolution; how to show that all apples grow on trees?

Tags: probability

I am reading a textbook with the following example:

If the statement 'All apples are fruit' is represented by $p(F=tr|A=tr)=1$ and 'All fruits grow on trees' by $p(T=tr|F=tr)=1$, and if we assume that whether or not something grows on a tree depends on whether or not it is a fruit, $p(T|A,F)=P(T|F)$

Then we can compute:
$$p(T=tr|A=tr) = \sum_F p(T=tr|F,A=tr)\underbrace{p(F|A=tr)}_{?} = \sum_F p(T=tr|F)p(F|A=tr)$$
$$=p(T=tr|F=fa)\underbrace{(F=fa|A=tr)}_{=0} + \underbrace{p(T=tr|F=tr)}_{=1}\underbrace{p(F=tr|A=tr)}_{=1} = 1$$

And so we have deduced that 'All apples grow on trees'. 
My question is about the term with the question mark below, I don't understand where it comes from. I thought that $ p(T=tr|A=tr)$ should be simply $ \sum_F p(T=tr|F,A=tr) $

Comment: What is $tr$? Presumably, $A$ means apple and $F$ means fruit.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist: I'm guessing $tr$ is "true".  But it's not clear.  Probability seems like an odd approach to this question.  OP: Is this the approach used in the textbook?  Or is the use of conditional probability your idea?

Comment: @Brian I suspected that, but then it seems odd to then think of apples, fruits, and trees being true or false. I mean, I understand what the notation is trying to convey, but I imagine there has to be a better way of expressing this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you have labeled with a question mark is going to follow from a few basic identities in probability.  Suppose that $A, B$, and $c$ are discrete random variables, taking values within the finite sets $\Omega_A$ and $\Omega_B$, respectively.  Then we have, for any $a \in \Omega_A$, $$P(A = a) = \sum_{b \in \Omega_B} P(A = a, B = b)$$  To introduce a conditional probability, we observe that $$\begin{align}P(A = a | C = c) &= \dfrac{P(A = a, C = c)}{P(C = c)}\\ &= \dfrac{\sum_{b \in \Omega_b} P(A = a, B = b, C = c)}{P(C = c)} \\ &= \sum_{b \in \Omega_B} P(A = a, B = b | C = c)\end{align}$$  We then observe that $$\begin{align} P(A = a | B = b, C = c) P(B = b | C = c) &= \dfrac{P(A = a, B = b, C = c)}{P(B = b, C = c)} \dfrac{P(B = b, C = c)}{P(C = c)} \\&= \dfrac{P(A = a, B = b, C = c)}{P(C = c)} \\&= P(A = a, B = b | C = c).\end{align}$$  Substituting this into the previous result, we have $$P(A = a | C = c) = \sum_{\Omega_B} P(A = a | B = b, C = c) P(B = b | C = c).$$

In your case, all of your random variables are binary, meaning they are "true" or "false."  We could also imagine them taking values in the set $\Omega_A = \Omega_B = \{0, 1\}$ or in $\{tr, fls\}$.  Either way, if we use this last result, we get $$P(T = tr | A = tr) = \sum_{f \in \{tr, fls\}} P(T = tr | F = f, A = tr) P(F = f | A = tr),$$ where your notes appear to have written this summation with slightly sparser notation.

Comment: Super clear - thanks!